# Primefaces fileupload multiple - doesn't want upload many files in one time

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I was trying to find solution and strange, that seems that I'm one with this problem.

I have primefaces fileupload component:

```
<p:fileUpload label="#{msg.get('btn.Browse')}" rendered="#{(taskCrud.inst.id != null)}"
    fileUploadListener="#{cmpFileUploadController.handleTaskFileUpload}" auto="true" multiple="true"
    update=":fTask:tskTab:fileList" disabled="#{!taskCrud.editable}">
</p:fileUpload>
```

And CDI bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CmpFileUploadController implements Serializable {

(...)

    public void handleTaskFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Uploading a file");
        fileUploadAction(event);
        task.addFile();
    }
}
```

When I try to upload one file, everything is ok, but when I try to upload multiple files, sometimes the `handleTaskFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)` method fires once (one file is uploaded), sometimes it is not fired, sometimes twice, but almost never the number times of files amount. 
I've tried with different scopes, no effect.

What is the problem?

**My configuration:**

Primefaces 4.0, JSF 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.18), JDK1.6.0_24

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which server are you deploying to?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Jboss EAP 6.1.0.Alpha (7.2.0.Final), thanks